# How to override ALT + CLICK Shortcut for Adding Multiple cursors in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

My Os: Linux Mint 20.1 is overriding Alt + Click for Adding multi-cursors in vs code.

Unfortunately i cannot change Linux Mint 20.1 shortcut , so my only choice is to override vs code shortcut, i tried looking at shortcuts on vs code but unable to find it.
I have the latest version of vs code.
Please help me.

Comment: Is your `Editor: Multi Cursor Modifier` setting still set to `alt`?  Or try the command `workbench.action.toggleMultiCursorModifier` Toggle multi-cursor modifer.

Comment: Dude that's it. Alt was selected, so i just pick CtrlCmd. Please post your answer, and i'll put it as the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a conflict with <kbd>Alt</kbd>, you do have the option to chose either <kbd>CtrlCmd</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> (the default) to get the multi-cursor functionality.  See this setting:

`Editor: Multi Cursor Modifier`

You can also toggle between using <kbd>CtrlCmd</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> with this keybinding:

```
{
    "key": "shift+alt+q",
    "command": "workbench.action.toggleMultiCursorModifier"
},
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you can override the Linux Mint Shortcut! If you navigate to `System Settings` > `Windows` > `Behavior`, you'll find the `Special key to move and resize windows` setting. You can change the key to your `Super` or `Ctrl`/`Cmd` key, or disable the setting entirely.

Comment: Thanks. This should be the real solution to "Adding Multi cursor in vscode".